# Is there an way to see a number of invocation per firebase function in the firebase console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-console

We are using a firebase platform for our recent projects. We recently launched and have been monitoring the usage.

I can see total number of firebase invocation in the firebase console but could not find the way of seeing the number of invocation for each function..

Could you please advice if there is any way of seeing these number?

We wanted to find the most used firebase functions.

We can expect which firebase functions would be mostly used, but wanted to know the exact number called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Firebase console doesn't offer a breakdown of invocations per function, but the Cloud console does. And since each Firebase project is also a project on the Cloud platform, you can just switch over to [console.cloud.google.com](https://console.cloud.google.com) to get the more detailed information.

Since the Cloud console is a bit trickier to navigate, here are the steps:

1. Go to [`console.cloud.google.com`](https://console.cloud.google.com).
2. Sign in if needed.
3. Select your project from the dropdown at the top.
4. In the search box () next to the project name, type and select `Cloud Functions`.
5. You'll now see a list of the functions in your project.
6. Click on the name of the function you want to see the invocations of.
7. You'll now see a chart of the invocations.

From one of my projects:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation, Frank. Now I can see the info per function!

Comment: This shows invocations/sec. Is there any way to get cummulative count per day/months, like we have invocation/day for all functions together?

Comment: @hkchakladar yes you can view data from all of the functions together using [Metrics Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-explorer) in the GCP Console under Monitoring.